# Dedicated monitor for displaying weather forecast

Tags: monitors

I'm looking for the minimum cost/complexity to have a dedicated monitor or display that shows a detailed weather forecast. This could be a smart display, although I don't want to have to use voice activation every time, or an economical set-up for accomplishing this with a mini PC/tablet.

I've done research on smart displays but it doesn't seem like they can be made to always show a detailed forecast, and I've seen weather stations but I want to get a forecast from the internet rather than local measurements which I've found to be imprecise. Let me know if are any specifications I'm forgetting to include. Thanks!